# AWS CloudHSM v5 (Cavium) : "No Such Algorithm" for RSASSA-PSS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rsa, fips, hardware-security-module

I'm using AWS CloudHSM to sign a hash, and previously was using the NONEwithRSA algorithm. AWS had advised us to move to using PSS padding for RSA signatures in light of the FIPS standard changing on 1/1/24.

I figured a quick change of the algorithm string to "RSASSA-PSS" [as described in the v5 document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/java-lib-supported_5.html) would be sufficient.

My logs are constantly showing the error "no such algorithm: RSASSA-PSS for provider Cavium"

What is the correct string to use here? Any reason why v5 won't support this even though it's in their official documentation? AWS only wants to see logs and hasn't been able to answer us about what string would work.

I've tried different iterations of the string, "RSA-PSS", "RSASSA/PSS", for example - no difference.